# CKEditor - how to save and display html code in rich text

Tags: html, tags, ckeditor

I had html textarea's with plain text, there are html code samples stored in MySQL.

I changed textarea's to ckeditor class. All is fine, but all html code blocks are not displayed now in rich text mode.

I've tried to use `<pre>` and `<code>` tags, but they are don't work.

Also I tried insertpre plugin, and it doesn't help.

Is there a way to display/save html code in CKEditor? How to ignore html tags in the block like on this site with Code Sample button?

**My example.**(Sorry, have no permissions to post images yet).

Textarea field:

`<textarea class="ckeditor" name = "description" >Text</textarea>`

I'm pasting code using "Insertpre" addon:

```
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
     <td>100</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

At once I see correct picture.

After form submit I get variable:
`$description=$_POST['description'];` and put it to database.

In database I see next value for this variable:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
&lt;table border=&quot;1&quot;&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
  &lt;td&gt;100&lt;/td&gt;
&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;</pre>
```

html form which displays data from base:

`<textarea class="ckeditor" name = "description" ><?php echo $description ?></textarea>`

When I open this form, I see empty code block, all html code is outside of pre-block, and I see a real table instead of html tags.

If I click on “Source” button , I see the same – table tags are not inside “pre” tags:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">

&nbsp;</pre>

<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As I understand, code saved in database in correct format, so problem somewhere in the output or in CKEditor behavior...

**Update: Found workaround:**
After long search I found similar problem in this topic: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/html-code-pre-tags-problem
Described workaround helped me: if I make output with *htmlspecialchars* php function it works good:

`<textarea class="ckeditor" name = "description" ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description) ?></textarea>`

I'm not sure is it a workaround or correct solution - after this all tags inserted in rich mode are displayed even without "pre" block. If yes - it should be in CKEditor FAQ, because this is very confusing.

Comment: Encoding issue. Show us a sample of your saved data and how you output it. It's always a good idea to show an example :). Show us both the encoded and not-encoded data; I'm guessing you have something like this: `<p>I'm awesome</p><pre>&lt;p&lt;WOO CODEZ&lt;p/&gt;</pre>`. Am I right? Even if I am, show us. And how you output it. And how it currently works. And how you want it to work. Examples are **awesome**.

Comment: Thank you for response. I've added my example. As I see, the problem is that code leaves "pre" tags in CKEditor textarea, but I can't understand why.

Comment: That is strange. This is a very good example and it should work as far as I can see. I can't say anything directly, hopefully someone else will see if there is something going on that we don't notice.

Comment: After a long search I found a similar problem in this topic: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/html-code-pre-tags-problem. Described workaround helped me: if I make output with htmlspecialchars function it works good (echo htmlspecialchars($description) )

Answer (score 2):

May be I'm late. But it will be good to share a solution that worked for me for the same problem so it might help someone.

I was having a similar problem with ckeditor, I saved the user inputs in my table and when I wanted to display the saved html in ckeditor instance it would simply ignore the html and  display nothing.

So I inspected the html on my console and found that it has `\r\n`. So I just removed them and when I served it back to the `ckeditor` after escaping the html, it worked.

Here is my ruby code:

```
html = "<p>Content comes here</p>\r\n"
```

In my view

```
CKEDITOR.instaces.my_editor.setData("#{raw(html.gsub('\r\n',''))}")
```

And it worked. Hope that helps.